# a light tool to monitor remote host

Tags: networking, monitoring

I would like a desktop tool that monitor some remote http hosts (got HTTP 200 status for a given list of url).

So Nagios or Hyperic do the job for a strong configuration, but I search a light workstation tool that do the same job.

This tool will show a green bullet into the task bar and just alert me on state change : eg. when some of host became not available. The icon will became red until this host be back...

Usecase : my current public/private git repository just shut down, my end-user documentation became unavailable, etc...

I would like a tool for a windows environment but I am interested in a tool on Linux too.

Do you know a free and light tool like this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple Google Chrome extension which handle remote page monitoring :

**Page Monitor** by Max Shawabkeh (ak. max99x )

- store extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd
- code (licence MIT) : http://code.google.com/p/pagemon-chrome-ext/
- author website : http://max99x.com/chrome-extensions/page-monitor